# Spark implicits not resolving inside of scope

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I have some scala/spark code that looks like this:

```
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val join: (Dataset[MyCaseClassA], Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
    a.joinWith(b,
      a("prop_a1") === b("prob_b1"),
      "left"
    ) //more code...
```

This works fine and compiles and everything. But lets say I want to do some functional programming, so I refactor the whole thing to:

```
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val join: (Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassA], Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
     a(Unit).joinWith(b(Unit),
        a("prop_a1") === b("prob_b1"),
        "left"
     ) //more code...
```

AFAIKT this should work just fine. However, what ends up happening is that IntelliJ immediately greys out `import sqlContext.implicits._`, and the methods `===` stops resolving with `value === is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`.

So for some reason, the `import sqlContext.implicits._` just doesn't work when passing functional arguments. My questions are:

1. Why does the implicit imports stop working?
2. What can I do make the imports work and still use function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the thing is not in implicits but in type mismatch (and implicits are very sensitive to types).

`Unit` in `a(Unit)`, `b(Unit)` [is the companion object](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Unit.scala#L31) of abstract class `Unit`. It doesn't have type `Unit` (it has type `Unit.type`). It's `()` that has type `Unit`.

`a(Unit)`, `b(Unit)` compile just because in Scala any type (e.g. `Unit.type`) can be transformed to `Unit`.

Also you can't write `a("prop_a1")`, `b("prob_b1")` because `a`, `b` are functions from `Unit`, you can't apply them to `String`.

So although

```
val join: (Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassA], Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
  a(Unit).joinWith(b(Unit),
    a(Unit)("prop_a1") === b(Unit)("prob_b1"),
    "left"
  ) //more code...
```

compile (similarly even

```
val join: (Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassA], Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
  a(1).joinWith(b("A"),
    a(true)("prop_a1") === b(???)("prob_b1"),
    "left"
  ) //more code...
```

would compile) it seems you actually meant

```
val join: (Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassA], Unit => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
  a(()).joinWith(b(()),
    a(())("prop_a1") === b(())("prob_b1"),
    "left"
  ) //more code...
```

Also it's a little weird to accept `Unit`, usually `Unit` is returned.

You could write

```
val join: (() => Dataset[MyCaseClassA], () => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
  a().joinWith(b(),
    a()("prop_a1") === b()("prob_b1"),
    "left"
  ) //more code...
```

Here `() => ...` aka `Function0[...]` is the type of no-argument functions.

Or you can write with [by-name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) arguments

```
val join: (=> Dataset[MyCaseClassA], => Dataset[MyCaseClassB]) => Dataset[AB] = (a, b) =>
  a.joinWith(b,
    a("prop_a1") === b("prob_b1"),
    "left"
  ) //more code...
```